# Very slow wifi ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, 16.04, wireless, thinkpad

Hey I have a new Lenovo Thinkpad e470.. My Wifi is very slow(50kbs). I have no idea what this is..... It worked earlier but now it stays at this low bit rate... I've run this script for wifi debugging the ouput is here:  https://paste.ubuntu.com/23708044/

Edit:

I recognized that my connection to other computers on my network is very slow too. I don't know if this helps.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yeah i hope it helps you to help me with my probldm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recognized that my driver name is ath10k_pci instead of ath10k.. So after I added to /etc/modprobe.d/ath10k.conf "options ath10k_pci nohwcrypt=1" and I also replaced the default network-manager with wicd and it worked very slow and stable now.